# Error al Compilar apk con firma en Adroid Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, compilar, firma-digital

Cuando intento compilar con la firma (es la primera vez que lo hago) me indica un error y me indica lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Indica que La operación solicitada no se puede realizar con una sección asignada a usuario abierta.
Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Esto puede pasar en cirscuntancias excepcionales. A mi nunca me ha pasado pero a compañeros si. Esto se debe a que hay algun proceso que está haciendo uso de tus archivos. Por ejemplo, el editor Visual Studio, el escáner RealTime del antivirus, o algo así. Prueba a cerrar el proyecto volverlo a abrir e incluso reiniciar. Quizás esto puede solucionarlo, ya que es un bloqueo de ejecución de archivos `.dll`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. funciono reiniciando